# How should I write my method to get the 'link' value from the result I get after searching through JSON?

Tags: python, json, class, oop

A Python beginner here. 
I am trying to figure out how to write a method that gets the 'link' value after searching the title of the song or after list is sorted, and get it to play.  Like for instance, I'll type the word 'Hurt' and it'll tell me that it's found.  The issue I'm having is trying to get its link and open the Youtube site.  The Json file loads perfectly fine. I just need to figure out the next step after the search.

The Json file is:

```
{"LinkCollection":

[{"title":"I Will Always Love You" , 
"artist":"Whitney Houston" ,
"link":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JWTaaS7LdU", 
"id":1},

{"title":"Killing Me Softly" , 
"artist":"Roberta Flack" ,
"link":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ2t5e7stVM", 
"id":2},

{"title":"Hero" , 
"artist":"Mariah Carey" ,
"link":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IA3ZvCkRkQ", 
"id":3},

{"title":"Hurt" , 
"artist":"Christina Aguliera" ,
"link":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwCykGDEp7M", 
"id":4},

{"title":"At Last" , 
"artist":"Etta James" ,
"link":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-cbOl96RFM", 
"id":5}
]}
```

The class is:

```
from pprint import pprint
import json
import operator
from operator import itemgetter
import webbrowser

dataFile = "Music_Database.json"

class MusicLink():

    def __init__(self):
        print "Karaoke"

    def loadData(self,dataFile):
        musicObject = []
        json_data=open(dataFile)
        musicObject = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
        return musicObject

    def searchSong(self,search):
        foundList = []
        musicObject=[]
        musicObject =self.loadData(dataFile)
        #pprint(musicObject["LinkCollection"])
        howmanySongs = len(musicObject["LinkCollection"])
        print "You have %s stored online" %  howmanySongs
        for counter in range(howmanySongs):
            print musicObject["LinkCollection"][counter]["title"]
            name = musicObject["LinkCollection"][counter]["title"].lower()
            print " ."  # show this when you start a new record
            lowerCaseSearch = search.lower() 
            didIfindIt =  name.find( lowerCaseSearch) 
            print didIfindIt
            if didIfindIt >= 0 :
                print "*" # show this when you find it
                foundList.append( musicObject["LinkCollection"][counter]) 
        return foundList

    def sortByTitle(self,foundMedia):
        sortedTitleList = []
        sortedTitleList = sorted(foundMedia, key=itemgetter('title'))
        return sortedTitleList

    def sortByArtist(self,foundMedia):
        print"here"
        pprint(foundMedia)
        sortedByArtistList = []
        sortedByArtistList = sorted(foundMedia, key=lambda song: (song['artist']),     reverse=True)
        return  sortedByArtistList

    def displayUrl(self,newSong):
    #can't figure out the next step
    return ""

    def playSong(self, url):
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
        return ""
```

And the main file is:

```
search = raw_input("Find this Song: ")
results= m.searchSong(search)
pprint(results)


sortedResultByTitle = m.sortByTitle(results)

print "Sorted by Title"
pprint(sortedResultByTitle)
```

Comment: Could you post only the values and what you want to get out of them? Your code is not the problem - the problem is what is not in your code. So could you make the problem clearer? E.g. by removing the code if possible?

Comment: I hope I made it clearer. I added the JSON code, but I won't remove the code just in case someone needs it to look over.

Comment: python style suggestion: You don't have to iterate over the index (`count`) of the song list, especially if you don't use the index for any other purpose: `for song in musicObject["LinkCollection"]:`. Now you can replace every `musicObject["LinkCollection"][counter]` by `song`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be your main-file

```
from pprint import pprint
import webbrowser
search = raw_input("Find this Song: ")
results= m.searchSong(search)
pprint(results)


sortedResultByTitle = m.sortByTitle(results)

print "Sorted by Title"

# expression: enumerate(sortedResultByTitle)
# explanation: this generates some kind of iterator, that puts the index of the every list-entry in front of it
# example: (0, first), (1, second), ... 
# 
# expression: list(enumerate(…))
# explanation: we know that enumerate returns some kind of iterator. for printing the contents, we have to build a sequence like a list.
# example: [ (0, first), (1, second), (2, third), ... ]
pprint(list(enumerate(sortedResultByTitle)))


"""
The following while-loop will continue looping until the break-statement is hit
and that will happen, if there is no error occurring within the try-clause
"""
while True:
    try:
        # throws an error, if input can not be converted to integer
        song_number = int(raw_input("Choose song by number: "))
        # throws an error, if song_number is not within those boundaries
        assert 0 <= song_number < len(sortedResultByTitle)
    except:
        print "Error"
    else:
        break

webbrowser.open_new_tab(sortedResultByTitle[song_number]['link'])
```

And I could not help to modify one of your methods. Less output but I think that was for debugging purpose anyway.

```
class MusicLink(object):
    #...
    def searchSong(self,search):
        musicObject = self.loadData(dataFile)
        """
        The following code-line is a list-comprehension. (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
        try to read it like a sentence
        Create a list of song(s) by taking every song in musicObject["LinkCollection"]
        but only if the lowercase search-string is within the song 's lowercase title 
        """
        return [song for song in musicObject["LinkCollection"] if search.lower() in song["title"].lower() ]
    #…
```

### After major edit I added the whole class implementation

You where not sure how to design a class, especially the methods. Thats my version of the whole thing.

```
import webbrowser
import json
from pprint import pprint
from operator import itemgetter
class MusicLink():
    """
    This class stores a list of songs.
    """
    #
    def __init__(self, lst = None):
        print "Karaoke"
        # you did not use any instance-variables in your class although this is the whole sense of writing a class:
        # store data in a structured way and use methods to deal with those data
        # that's the way to store an instance variable: self.instance_variable = value
        self._songlist = lst or []
        """
        a = lst or [] 
        # same like means
        if lst is None: # short and more general: if not lst:
            a = []
        else:
            a = lst 
        """
        #
    def loadData(self,dataFile):
        # you watched the video, so have heard about with... advantage: you don't have to close the file
        with open(dataFile) as json_data:
            # the json-data are stored in the class variable
            self._songlist = json.load(json_data)["LinkCollection"]
        #
    def searchSong(self,search):
        """
        The following code-line is a list-comprehension. (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
        try to read it like a sentence
        Create a list of song(s) by taking every song in musicObject["LinkCollection"]
        but only if the lowercase search-string is within the song 's lowercase title 
        """
        return MusicLink([song for song in self._songlist if search.lower() in song["title"].lower() ])
        # instead of returning a list, I return a MusicLink-Object, so I can use all the other method on it
        #
    def sortByTitle(self):
        # instead of deliver the foundMedia it sorts the data in the instance-variable
        return MusicLink(sorted(self._songlist, key=itemgetter('title')))
        # sorted returns a list and that is what MusicLink needs to create a new, sorted instance
        #
    def sortByArtist(self):
        #pprint(foundMedia)
        # ^- I uncommented this line, because it is not good, if two similar functions like sortByTitle and sortByArtist differ in printing behaviour
        sortedByArtistList = sorted(self._songlist, key=itemgetter('artist'), reverse=True)
        return  MusicLink(sortedByArtistList)
        #
    def chooseSong(self):
        print "CHOOSE SONG BY NUMBER"
        pprint(dict(enumerate(self._songlist)))
        #
        while True:
            try:
                entered = int(raw_input('Enter your song number (not id):'))
                chosen_song = self._songlist[entered]
            except:
                # this happens, if var entered isnot int or if it is out of range of songlist
                print " -> Not found!"
            else:
                print " -> Play song..."
                break
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(chosen_song['link'])
```

**And that's how to use it:**

```
ml = MusicLink()
Karaoke

ml.loadData('jsontest.json')

ml.chooseSong()
CHOOSE SONG BY NUMBER
{0: {u'artist': u'Whitney Houston',
     u'id': 1,
     u'link': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JWTaaS7LdU',
     u'title': u'I Will Always Love You'},
 1: {u'artist': u'Roberta Flack',
     u'id': 2,
     u'link': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ2t5e7stVM',
     u'title': u'Killing Me Softly'},
 2: {u'artist': u'Mariah Carey',
     u'id': 3,
     u'link': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IA3ZvCkRkQ',
     u'title': u'Hero'},
 3: {u'artist': u'Christina Aguliera',
     u'id': 4,
     u'link': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwCykGDEp7M',
     u'title': u'Hurt'},
 4: {u'artist': u'Etta James',
     u'id': 5,
     u'link': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-cbOl96RFM',
     u'title': u'At Last'}}

Enter your song number (not id):3
 -> Play song...

ml.searchSong("you").chooseSong()
Karaoke
CHOOSE SONG BY NUMBER
{0: {u'artist': u'Whitney Houston',
     u'id': 1,
     u'link': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JWTaaS7LdU',
     u'title': u'I Will Always Love You'}}

Enter your song number (not id):2
 -> Not found!

Enter your song number (not id):2
 -> Not found!

Enter your song number (not id):0
 -> Play song...
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, koffein. I appreciate it! The code is working. If you still have some time, do you mind explaining your code because I want to learn Python as much as possible.

Comment: @user2843235 I add some comments to my code, in would advise, to watch this [Python video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go). I hope it is worth watching, though you claim yourself a python beginner.

Comment: @user2843235 since you are new to stack overflow, I just wanted to point out: please consider up-voting and/or checking my answer

Comment: The video was very informative.  I like how Python can be powerful even if the codes are simple. And okay, I checked your answer. Also, how do you know what methods to put when making class?  This is the part that got me frustrated the most.

Comment: If your method uses the object `self` in some way: if a method extracts and returns information of your object (in a wide sense "getter") or modifies your object, than it seems to be correct class design. I will add some advise to my answer, concerning your specific class